# Angular 10 Unit test - Component instance is returning undefined

Tags: angular, angular10, angular-test

Am getting undefined value on the component instance. It was working before i upgraded from angular 8 to angular 10. The only thing i change in my test is , async() to waitForAsync() as async was deprecated.

```
 describe('ProtocolInfoComponent', () => {
      let component: ProtocolInfoComponent;
      let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProtocolInfoComponent>;
    
      const mockActivatedRoute = new MockActivatedRoute({
        parent: new MockActivatedRoute({
          params: of({ studyId: 1001 })
        })
      });
    
      beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
          imports: [FormsModule,
            AppConfigModule,
            SharedModule,
            HttpClientTestingModule
          ],
          declarations: [ ProtocolInfoComponent ],
          providers: [
            { provide: UserService, useClass: UserServiceStub },
          { provide: APP_CONFIG_STUB, useClass: APP_DI_CONFIG_STUB },
            { provide: StudySetupService, useClass: StudySetupServiceStub },
            { provide: StudyCreateService, useClass: StudyCreateServiceStub },
            { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
            { provide: Router, useClass: RouterStub }]
          })
          .compileComponents().then(() => {
            AppInjector.setInjector(TestBed.inject(Injector));
          });
      }));
    
      beforeEach(() => {
        console.log('TestBed', TestBed.createComponent(ProtocolInfoComponent));
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProtocolInfoComponent);
        console.log('Fixture',fixture);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        console.log('Component',component);
        fixture.detectChanges();
      });
    
      it('should create', () => {
        console.log('=====component=====',component)
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
      });
    
      it('should have the study', () => {
        expect(component.study).not.toBe(null);
      });
    
      it('should have the responsibiltiies', () => {
        expect(component.responsibilities).not.toBe(null);
        expect(component.orgResponsibilities).not.toBe(null);
      });
});
```

I had console statements in my test to see whats the value for fixture and component. Both are undefined.
It work on other test, i had the same
any Idea on how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Finally able to figure it out. In the providers array one of the provide is useValue instead of useClass;

```
{ provide: APP_CONFIG_STUB, useValue: APP_DI_CONFIG_STUB }
```